# Install Ubuntu on iMac 21.5" (mid 2011)

Tags: windows, ati, intel, macosx

I has a dual boot system with MacOSX 10.8.2 and Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium x64. I would like to install Ubuntu alongside the two existing operating systems for cross platform development purposes. My System specs are listed below.

- iMac 21.5-inch (mid 2011)
- Intel Core i7 @2.80GHz
- AMD Radeon HD 6770M
- Facetime HD Internet Camera
- Thunderbolt port
- Wireless Airport adapter card
- Apple 8x Superdrive
- Apple Magic Mouse and wired keyboard with numeric keypad

Will rEFIt install properly on my machine too?

Thanks you very much for the help.

Comment: I have had no joy on the past with rEFIt or rEFInd plus almost all of those booters are not supported anymore. Take the plunge, boot to a USB with the Ubuntu iso installer and then when your grub breaks down the askubuntu community can help you get grub to load with your three OS options.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really nice tutorial on ubuntuforums about Triple Booting on iMac.
Here is the link 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1908210